# target hardware atmega2560, but register symbol unresolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, arduino

I am using `eclipse` for my arduino mega project development (I am using object oriented programming and I am more comfortable with `eclipse`).

I have chosen my target hardware as `atmega2560`, but many of the registers (e.g. `TIMSK`, `TCCR3B`) are unresolved. I am assuming that the compiler is pointing to `avr/iom16.h`. How can I make it point to `avr/iom2560.h`?

These symbols are resolved correctly in `Arduino-IDE`.

Comment: Since you told us the IDE, now edit your post with the compiler version you are using.  Eclipse will work with many different compilers.

Comment: If you are using GCC like the IDE, can you check that the correct flag is sent: `-mmcu=atmega2560`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem, but first you have to check that the issue is other than loss header files, so, once you have already cheked that this is not the problem, then is an IDE problem.
The solution could be:
go to: *Window->preferences->C/C++->indexer*  page,
then check the option *index all header variants*.
I hope this helps.

Well, at least worked for me on Eclipse Mars, AVR-gcc tool chain, Linux :P